# How to rotate report by 90 degree clockwise?

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.1.1 and I have design *JasperReports* report with Landscape Orientation.

But my requirement is that, I want to print that Landscape PDF in Portrait mode **without changing its orientation manually** (i.e. from Page Setup Option or any other option).

Hence I am going to **Rotate the generated sample PDF by 90 degree clockwise**.
Anybody have solution over these scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the orientation of PDF in JasperReports by 90 degree clockwise, we can **design report with Portrait Orientation by putting their custom width and height.**

i.e. We just need to set **pageWidth = height of landscape report** & **pageHeight = width of landscape report.**

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. The directions of the report rows and pagination must be aligned. You will have to transpose your report.